# Knowing the state of an object using the state pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, state-pattern

I am using the state pattern and I need to know in which state a given object is to print it. I thought about using an abstract method returning a string that each state would override with its own name, is it an acceptable solution?

```java
public abstract class State{

    public abstract String getState();

}

class StateOne extends State{

    @Override
    public String getState(){ return "StateOne"; }

}

// And so on for each state...
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with this. The state classes must vary the actions that they perform based on their current state, and this can be one of those actions.

Comment: I would rather use an interface `WithState` and make the classes that have a State implement it. This is more flexible than using inheritance. Always choose [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) when available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have is **"is a"** relationship, so it is okay to put abstract method `getState()` in abstract class:

```
public abstract class State{

    public abstract String getState();

}
```

Abstract class should contain behaviour for all derived classes. `getState()` method is planned to use in all derived classes. In addition, `getState()` method has very high cohesion with `State` class. So this is a case when to use inheritance.

[Read more when to prefer inheritance or composition.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354/1646240)